# Add Choice on Button Click

Tags: android

I want to add choice on Save of button. After clicking on save button it must ask me "do you want to upload on server".

My code

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        previewCapturedImage();
    } 
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you heard about dialog boxes

Comment: Please improve your question. Currently I cannot relate your question to your code.

Comment: @PSK There is no need to indent the lines so far.

Comment: @nandini use my code and let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 1):

Use alert dialog in your code.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // your code goes here
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the following options :

1. **AlertDialog** - using an alertDialog , one can add a text like (say) "Do you want to save?" and add a positive button "Yes" and a negative button "No".
2. **Custom Dialog** - by creating an object of Dialog like : `Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(this);`and then using `myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.mycustomlayout);`you can add your own custom created layout where you have textview with text "Do you want to save?" and Button "Save".
3. **PopUp Window** - you can add a popUpWindow like used in youtube and googlePlayStore to show provide a list of options user wants to select.

Comment: this answer can make more perfect if some more efforts you put in this code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for this code

On Click of the save button use this code.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Upload Image");
        alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // this is where u can save the image function 

                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
}
```